# can wife do 2nd Marriage without asking her husband

Tags: tafseer, sunni

can a wife do 2nd marriage without her husband permisssion???

like a married boy and a married girl wants to get married again , so can they do marriage without permission???

Comment: Could you try to express yourself more? What do you mean with "can a wife do a second marriage without her husbands permission?"

Answer (score 1):

No. It is forbidden for women to have more than one husband.

Allah (ﷻ) prohibited men from marrying already-married women. He said:

> **And [also prohibited to you are all] married women** except those your right hands possess. [This is] the decree of Allah upon you. And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these, [provided] that you seek them [in marriage] with [gifts from] your property, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse.. [Qur'an (4:24)].

As for "without asking permission" - SubhanAllah. Even if her husband *agrees*, it is not accepted in Islam.. let alone doing it behind his back. And for a man to let another man lay with his wife is reprehensible (cuckoldry). Plus, women are naturally monogamous/shy so what kind of evil/shameful woman would desire such a thing?!

Both parties need to fear Allah (ﷻ).

The married woman needs to go back to her husband and reject the influence of Satan tempting her with others; she needs to draw nearer to her husband and cut off interaction with all  other non-mahrams. If there are issues within the marriage which are causing this swaying away then she needs to work with her husband to overcome them. Otherwise, ask for a divorce/separation. -- But she cannot have two husbands or be involved with two men. It would be Zina (adultery).

The man can marry a 2nd woman but she has to be single (unmarried). He should fear Allah (ﷻ) and stay away from women who are already married.

Comment: It is not clear if that was his question.

Comment: He said "2nd marriage" without asking for 'permission of husband' . If it was not at the same time, then it would be "ex-husband" and his permission wouldn't be needed to begin with.

Comment: Yes but his second statement doesn't make it sound so clear: "like a married boy and a married girl wants to get married again"... What does he mean with again? Maybe he speaks about a divorced couple getting married again or something. not sure becuse it's not clear

Comment: Also a second marriage doesn't mean you are married with two persons.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeking to make things more complicated than they really are. Did he mention divorce or an ex-husband *anywhere*? No. So that is the apparent meaning of the question.. asking whether she needs to ask her current husband to marry a 2nd. -- Unless he (OP) specifies otherwise, no point in arguing about my answer.

Comment: i get my answer, i know what i have to do know , thanks alot